# Create Sqlite Table with unique entries

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to create a Sqlite table with some column how has unique entries like:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Links(Id integer primary key autoincrement, Name TEXT, Link TEXT UNIQUE)")
```

After that I try to insert data into these DB:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Links (Name, Link) VALUES(?, ?)", links)
```

But I get:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Links.Link
```

Whats wrong here and how to solve the error?

Comment: Is there already data in the DB?

Comment: No I create a new one

Comment: Ah, the insert was failing. I didn't notice that.

Comment: This is not a forum. If you have an answer, write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error. When I was executing only these:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Links(Id integer primary key autoincrement, Name TEXT, Link TEXT UNIQUE)")UNIQUE)")
```

There was no error! Only when I have tried to insert date into these DB like:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Links (Name, Link) VALUES(?, ?)", links)
```

And that was throwing the error! I only has to change `INSERT` into `INSERT OR IGNORE` to solve it like:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Links (Name, Link) VALUES(?, ?)", links)
```

The `INSERT OR IGNORE` while putting data into my DB solved the error in my case!